# Which is the best? Roles based App or Table per Type?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I'm recently working on an application that requires 2 user types. Physicians and General Users. They share some attributes (for example Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, Gender, etc).
But Physicians also need some other attributes that General Users does not have it. Fore example Physicians may have Speciality and WorkingPlace. I found that I should use Table Per Type Inheritance (TPT) in Entity Framework. I created a abstract base class named People, also I created two subclass named (RegisteredUser and Phisycian) inherit from People abstract class.

I Also found that the default Membership Provider in ASP.NET is not suitable for my needs. So I developed a CustomMembershipProvider class that can now work with Table per Type inheritance in Entity Framework.

But I think that it can be very better that I use Roles instead of Table Per Type inheritance. So I want to change my application for using Roles. But the problem is that how can I handle different attributes for Phisycians and General Users? I need a solution that can handle multiple profile fields for multiple User roles. For example if a User is in Physician role, he should have Speciality and WorkingPlace attributes.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

How about [using Simple Membership with Roles](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)?

You can use Custom Attributes for the specific User Types (Physicians, GeneralUsers ) like so.

```
public class PhysicianProfile : ProfileBase
{
    public string WorkingPlace { 
        get { return this["WorkingPlace"]; }
        set { this["WorkingPlace"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But now how can I distinguish between 2 user types. For example how can I find that which profile belongs to a physician and which one is for General User?

Comment: Hope I understand your question correctly. Can't you use something like `if ( someProfileObject.GetType() == typeof(PhysicianProfile)) )` where `someProfileObject` is your userProfile instance?